# sample on quartz scheduler thread pool

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Please give me the sample on quartz scheduler using thread pooling in java

Answer (score 2):

OReilly has an [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/09/28/what-is-quartz.html?page=2) detailing the Quartz configuration for thread-pooling. Put the following in your `quartz.properties`.

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount =  5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
```