# Thread Pool Implementation in java or java open sources for Quartz handling?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

The thread pool can be configured in Quartz via the quartz property - org.quartz.threadPool.class

please help and let me know what are the best implementation available in Java (or) list of Java open sources which have the ThreadPool implementations where we can

a) Kill a Quartz Job (i.e) the current executing Thread and create a new Thread since the thread count 
should be not reduced in the Quartz scheduler due to this job removal
b) Option to just kill the Quartz Job (i.e) current executing thread and manually create a new thread for 
the same since we have killed the same to terminate the process.

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it... http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Spring in your project, then it comes with a [TaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler-implementations) (thread  pool) for Quartz. Or you can use the inbuilt thread pool. Look at this post [sample on quartz scheduler thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518558/sample-on-quartz-scheduler-thread-pool)

You can start from here [How to cancel a scheduled job in Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269754/how-to-cancel-a-scheduled-job-in-quartz)

Comment: could you please let me know how we can achieve point a) and b) ?

Comment: @Kathir you shouldn't edit an existing question to ask more questions. Ask each of those questions in a separate post.